# How to develop node js (create-react-app) without installing node js using docker

Tags: node.js, docker, create-react-app

Hi I wanted to develop `create-react-app` based project using docker without installing `NodeJS` on my machine.
I have this `Dockerfile.dev` file

```
FROM node:lts
VOLUME ./:/usr/src/app # mount my react project on container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm start
```

However, when I run `docker build -f .\Dockerfile.dev .` I get this error

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

I can see that maybe the `VOLUME` command wasn't successful. How do I fix or make it work? Maybe docker-compose is better?

*PS: I don't want to copy project files, since it's not production or deployment scenario, and auto refresh on file change won't work.*

Comment: It is strictly easier to install Node than to install Docker, and if you install Node, there's never a problem of making your host-system files available to your host-system Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VOLUME in Dockerfile is not what you need , just use -v option and set your dockerfile as :

```
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
CMD npm install && npm start
```

build and start the container:

```
docker build -t MYIMAGE . && docker run -tid -v ./app:/usr/src/app MYIMAGE
```

compose:

```
volumes:
       - ./app:/usr/src/app
```

command:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Comment: Can you include docker-compose file that does that below command?

Comment: updated the answer, the dockerfile should be the same, only add the volumes section

Comment: So does that mean `CMD npm install && npm start` executes when the container starts, not when the image is built right?

Comment: I'm getting `/bin/sh: 1: npm install && npm start: not found` error

Comment: Giving `image: nested-route-example-dev:latest` image name in `.yml` works. Any idea why?

Comment: Auto reload doesn't work though. Changing mounted volume's file should change it inside container right?

Comment: Yes that is right , you can check by `docker exec CONATINER cat /usr/src/app/MYFILE`

Comment: The file has changed, but refreshing shows old file, also auto reload doesn't work.